# QueryStringParameter not being passed to SqlDataSource during Insert operation

Tags: asp.net, query-string, detailsview

I'm trying to make a page that allows the user to insert records into the database depending on a value passed via the query string. The query string contains a key called ProductID which matches the SQL column I'm trying to make it insert into.

The URL is constantly something like: ViewProductDetails.aspx?ProductID=1
I can confirm that the query value is set because the page also loads entries using this supplied product ID.

What doesn't work, as I've said, is inserting records into the database. I have the following InsertCommand.

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [ProductDetails] ([ProductID], [Color], [Size], [Quantity]) VALUES (@ProductID, @Color, @Size, @Quantity)"
```

I have the following insert parameters.

```
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ProductID" QueryStringField="ProductID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Color" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Size" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Quantity" Type="Int32" />
</InsertParameters>
```

I have the following DetailsView:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="InsertDetailsView" runat="server" DataSourceID="ProductDetailsDataSource" Height="50px" Width="500px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="ProductDetailID" DefaultMode="Insert" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnItemInserted="InsertDetailsView_ItemInserted">
    <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#CCFFCC" ForeColor="#663300" />
    <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#FFFF99" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Times New Roman" Width="100px" Wrap="False" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Size" SortExpression="Size">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="SizeDropDown" runat="server" DataSourceID="ProductSizesDataSource" DataTextField="Size" DataValueField="Size" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProductSize") %>' />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Color" HeaderText="Color" SortExpression="Color" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowCancelButton="False" ShowInsertButton="True" />
    </Fields>
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Trying to insert a record however, results in.

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ProductID', table 'devdb.ProductDetails'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Am I possibly missing something that for some reason causes the query field to be ignored?